# disable/override -Werror=sign-compare

Tags: c++

I assume this question has been asked in different ways but I couldn't find an answer for my case.
There is a codebase with a XYZ.mk file which includes other make files from different places. Somewhere, in the build system, `-Werror=sign-compare` has been enabled and I need to temporarily disable it in XYZ.mk (or via command line: `gmake -f XYZ.mk [some option]`) while I am making my changes locally. But I don't know how?!

Appreciate your help.

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking how to specify a flag for only one or a set of source files? Or what flag to use to disable the error?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The latter option: disable that flag totally, for now.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable any error by using the "enable" flag but prefixing it with a "no".

As in `-Wno-error=sign-compare`.

---

Note that this will still show as a warning, if it's enabled as a warning.

To also disable the warning use `-Wno-sign-compare`.